# Cant properly manage the onTouchEventListteners in expandableListView

Tags: listview, ontouchlistener, onitemlongclicklistener

I created Expandable list and set gesturedetector which acts like Slider(it shows and hides every time i make fling on it).

```
expListListener= new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){

    @Override public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

                expandableListView.invalidateViews();

                Thread closeSliderThread = new Thread(new closingSlider());
                Thread openingSliderThread = new Thread(new openingSlider());

                    if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() < 0 && Math.abs(e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > difference) {
                       closeSliderThread.start();                   
                       for (int i = 0; i < expandableListView.getCount(); i++)             expandableListView.collapseGroup(i);

                       return true;
                     }


                    if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > 0
                            && Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > difference)
                    {

                       openingSliderThread.start();                                                              
                       return true;
                    }
                    return false;

            }



            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {

                return true;
            }

             class closingSlider implements Runnable{
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     rightPartLL.post(new Runnable() {
                         @Override
                         public void run() {
                             synchronized (closingSlider.class) {
                                 rightPartLL.startAnimation(hide_slider);
                             }
                         }
                     });

                 }
             }
            class openingSlider implements Runnable{
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    rightPartLL.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            synchronized (openingSlider.class) {
                                rightPartLL.startAnimation(show_slider);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
```

then

```
gestureDetectorOfExpListView = new GestureDetector(activity,expListListener);
```

here i tell the expanableList to listen on my fling actions:

```
expandableListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            return gestureDetectorOfExpListView.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

        }


    });enter code here
```

But when i tried to set an OnItemLongListener in order to implement logic after long touch the child of ExpandableList:

```
expandableListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id) == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
                int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);
                int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(id);

                Toast.makeText(activity,"group: "+groupPosition +" child:"+childPosition,5000).show();

                // Return true as we are handling the event.
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
enter code here
```

...and it doesn`t work.But when i delete then lines where i set

```
OnTouchEvent to expandableListView which return return gestureDetectorOfExpListView.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
```

....`OnItemLongClickListener` works properly! Help me to figure out how to implement both- gesture actions and `onLongTouches` as well. Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

So i found an elegant solution:

```
xpandableListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            return gestureDetectorOfExpListView.onTouchEvent(motionEvent) | expandableListView.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

        }


    });enter code here
```